# Error Creating tokens in Contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Basically I followed the code and full code tutorials to create tokens on TESTNET. Contracts show as created but no tokens exist.

First I increased all gas, then I tried following prior errors here: 
[Following token tutorial on ethereum.org, get error message "No data is deployed on the contract address"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/following-token-tutorial-on-ethereum-org-get-error-message-no-data-is-deployed)

I've tried with or without mods in  this fix done last year but no difference.

Heres a hash error message.

https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x0b714025a02eca2763f2a5c43364da07f7484ed04cd83947e31324e57e3199dd

Really trying to adopt this ETH proof of concept but seem to hit a wall

Heres the code I'm using. http://ethereum.org/token#the-code its from the "The code" tutorial section of Ethereum's Creating your own cryptocurrency page. Had links before but as a noob was limited to 2 links per post. The constructor parameters are Supply: 10000 Name:EATEST Symbol: ETR2 Decimals:2 code starts with

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2; 

    contract tokenRecipient { 

    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);

    }
}
```

I click Deploy button,sign and after creation, it displays the red "No data is deployed.."

Comment: Can you post the contract code you're actually deploying? Also, either the script or commands you're using to do the deployment.

Comment: Thanks for  the assistance. Heres the code I'm using.  https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code
its from the "The code" tutorial section of Ethereum's Creating your own cryptocurrency page. Had links before but as a noob was limited to 2 links per post.
The constructor parameters are
 Supply: 10000 Name:EATEST Symbol: ETR2 Decimals:2  
code starts with pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); } I click Deploy button,sign and after creation, it displays the red "No data is deployed.." message

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a direct answer, but I'm posting a comment here so you can see a picture.

It's really hard to say what might be going wrong (numerous tool setup and procedural possibilities), but this workaround could get things moving again. Many developers prefer Browser Solidity, recently renamed to Remix at https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity.

Below, I've just copied and pasted the source file, and "created" the MyToken contract. You can see the functions on the right, including the initial supply. This tool gives fast turnaround with an in-memory blockchain "emulator" ... so no long delays for mining. Also a real-time compiler.

Takes some getting used to, but a lot of developers prefer it for casual work. I think it might bring more joy.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Sorry.. accidentally submitted prior post on enter command. 
 
Anyway, Its 4 months later and admit it was Solidity and MEW that really got me through! Ethereum Wallet has quite a reputation I found out and there's far better alternatives esp as a noob. Solidity at first looked very intimidating but I learned to wrestle the beast and setup the token! 

 Id recommend anyone new to avoid Ethereum wallet if  still learning given the setups and config involved.